A question about typescript union type narrowing
I try to write a react component that renders form by config using typescript. A ts problem borderd me, here is the code:
interface SelectProps {
  options: string[];
}
interface InputProps {
  value: string;
}

interface InputConfig {
  type?: 'Input',
  componentProps: InputProps
}
interface SelectConfig {
  type: 'Select',
  componentProps: SelectProps
}

type Config =  SelectConfig | InputConfig;

const configs: Config[] = [
  {
    componentProps: {
      value: '123',
      // I expect that componentProps should be InputProps(type is not declare) and options should cause ts error, but it doesn't, why ?
      options: ['456']
    }
  }
]

What I want is config should be InputConfig when type is not decleared, how can I reach this ?

TS unions aren't exclusive, and excess property checking doesn't kick in if the property exists in any member of a union. If you want to say that SelectProps and InputProps are mutually exclusive you need to tell TS that the cross-terms don' exist, possibly as shown in this playground link. See linked q/a for more information.

@jcalz Isn't the problem rather that Config is not discriminated on type when that is sometimes optional?

I suppose you could look at it that way. If it were considered a discriminated union then excess property checks would cause the desired error. Of course the same issue would be there as shown in this playground link although it would be a little harder to trip over... I'm not sure how much OP cares about prohibiting the cross-terms.

I  simplify my example in this link. What I want is SelectConfig and InputConfig are exclusive. Is it possible ? @jcalz

SelectProps and InputProps have many properties, and other componentConfigs(many) are unlisted above. So It's not easy to add never to componentProp interface mutually.

You can use ExclusifyUnion from the linked q/a to do it automatically, as shown in this playground link

It's not what I expect. Options should complain when type is not declared, just as type is "Input"

Sorry, you're right. The union you need to exclusify is nested. You could write something like this version instead.

Yes, this could help me. Thinks.
